# Can't present view controller

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a function that checks if the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in I want to present a login view controller. But as I mentioned in the title, the view controller is not shown. In addition, the initial view controller is not the login view controller (which is set in a storyboard and is a tab bar view controller). In fact, that view controller is in a different storyboard. Is that the problem?

```
private func validateAuth(){
    if FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginAndRegisterStoryboard", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController")
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I tried to set the breakpoint to the function. The debugger says that the function is executed but the view controller is not shown. Any solutions?
And yes, the function is called.

Comment: So, when you can verify that `storyboard.instantiateViewController()` actually returned a view controller, one reason why presenting it may fail is, that `self` already presents another view controller. So, you might verify this as well utilsing the debugger console: `po self.presentedViewController` should be `nil`.

Comment: You state that the `validateAuth()` function is called but you don't tell us anything else. What happens as you step through the code? Do you get inside the `if` statement? Do you reach the call to `self.present`? Is there any message in the console when `self.present` is executed?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper yes it is 'nil' when I execute `po self.presentedViewController`

Comment: @HangarRash Yes, it reachs to `self.present` but the only presented viewcontroller is the initial viewcontroller which is set through storyboard

Comment: Can you remove Firebase from the equation and create a basic ViewController which just unconditionally presents your LoginViewController. Just modify what you have and show a bit more code. There may be other reasons, and you need to narrow it down to find the culprit. Just ensure that your LoginViewController _can_ be presented at all.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I created blank viewcontroller and inserted the code without firebase but result is the same

Comment: Well, now I guess we can only give some rough ideas what to do. So, the next steps are hunting the bug. ;)  Creativity will help a lot.
You may create a new vanilla View Controller first programmatically, then in storyboard. Check. Is it your parent view controller? Make a new one, check. Is it a broken storyboard file, create a new one with a vc in it, check, ...

Comment: Is `self` the current presented viewController? Who call that method? Could you show the code? I guess it's an instance issue (wrong instance, usually by creating a new one and thinking it's another one).